# Difference between Request["xx"] and Request.Form["xx"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any difference between `Request["xx"] vs Request.Form["xx"]` ?

I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former will return a value if `xx` exists in the `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, or `ServerVariables` collections. It will go through each one in turn till it finds a value, at which point it will return.

See the documentation on [the indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) of `HttpRequest`.

In short, if you have a `?xx=123` on the query string, and you use `Request["xx"]`, the string "123" will be returned, regardless of an `xx` key existing in the `Form` collection.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I was answering from memory. Answer updated according to official documentation.

Comment: Strange that MS doesn't specify the _order_ until it finds the first value....(just curious).

Answer (score 3):

`Request["key"]` retrieves the value from **Cookies**,  **Form**, **QueryString** or **ServerVariable**.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx):

> The QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collection member specified in the key parameter. If the specified key is not found, then Nothing is returned.

Where `Request.Form["key"]` retrieves it from the form (POST) collection explicitly.